# Obtain distinct row and * from one table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

I'm trying obtain one tabla of cars which have three rows in relations with other three columns (make, model and group) and I only want obtain one car by model.

Here a image of MySQL table: 
[image]

You will see three rows with same model_id (model_id is foreign key the other table, the other table is called models)

My SQL query for obtain those cars are:

```
SELECT *
FROM gm_cars AS cars
INNER JOIN gm_cars_makes AS makes
   ON (cars.make_id = makes.make_id)
INNER JOIN gm_cars_models AS models
   ON (cars.model_id = models.model_id)
INNER JOIN gm_cars_groups AS groups
   ON (cars.group_id = groups.group_id) AND
       makes.make_visible = 1
ORDER BY cars.model_id;
```

but I wish obtain one row for one model, here one example (I have used Photoshop):
[image]

Some like: `SELECT *, DISTINCT(model_id) FROM cars`

Comment: Question is what columns besides the model id you want? you can group data together with a 'group by' clause. if you just want the ids you can do 'select distinct model_id from cars'

Comment: How do we know what value to select for `car_doors` - two rows say 5, one row says 3?

Comment: Why is this question tagged both MySQL and SQL Server? Which platform are you actually using? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc7B7.png

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to return all columns, you can create sub-query to return only one Car per Model and then write you query as before:

```
SELECT * FROM gm_cars AS cars 
INNER JOIN (SELECT model_id, MAX(car_Id) AS car_Id FROM gm_cars GROUP BY model_id) AS grp_cars ON grp_cars.car_Id = cars.car_Id
INNER JOIN gm_cars_makes AS makes ON (cars.make_id = makes.make_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_models AS models ON (cars.model_id = models.model_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_groups AS groups ON (cars.group_id = groups.group_id) AND makes.make_visible = 1 ORDER BY cars.model_id;
```

You can also add `GROUP BY` in you main query, and add aggregation function to all other columns. But it can return you columns from different cars with the same model:

```
SELECT cars.model_id,
    MAX(car_passengers),
    MAX(car_suitcases),
    ....
FROM gm_cars AS cars 
INNER JOIN (SELECT model_id, MAX(car_Id) AS car_Id FROM gm_cars GROUP BY model_id) AS grp_cars ON grp_cars.car_Id = cars.car_Id
INNER JOIN gm_cars_makes AS makes ON (cars.make_id = makes.make_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_models AS models ON (cars.model_id = models.model_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_groups AS groups ON (cars.group_id = groups.group_id) AND makes.make_visible = 1 
GROUP BY cars.model_id
ORDER BY cars.model_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM gm_cars AS cars 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_makes AS makes ON (cars.make_id = makes.make_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_models AS models ON (cars.model_id = models.model_id) 
INNER JOIN gm_cars_groups AS groups ON (cars.group_id = groups.group_id) 
AND makes.make_visible = 1 
group by (model_id)
ORDER BY cars.model_id
```

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful?

```
    ;with cte 
    AS
    (
        Select *,row_number() OVER(partition by model_id order by car id) rn from gm_cars 
    )

    select * from cte where rn=1
```